# Google Fonts API returns 403 on AMP page

Tags: fonts, google-api, amp-html

I was excited that I finally got my AMP page validating, but I always get a 403 Forbidden when https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Georgia|Times+New+Roman is called.  I've followed the [AMP Example for article page](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/examples/article.amp.html).  Has anyone else run into this?

Comment: A 403 Forbidden error occurs when the request for the Web font file cannot be validated. The page's domain/subdomain has not been added to the Web font project's domain list. The Web font you are trying to use has not yet been published since the page's domain/subdomain was added. You can find the available Google Fonts [here](https://www.google.com/fonts).

Comment: @abielita thanks for the information. Any ideas why I would see the server getting a 403 loading the Google Fonts onto the site's editor and the other developer form another country does not see the 403? Makes no sense to me..

Answer (score 2):

here's my implementation, I just tested and it seems to work :

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Comment: I had to use `type='text/html'` before it worked for me - Page Speed Insights was also throwing an error on this.